# Getting data/information for android app use

Tags: java, android

I have been wondering about this, which is why I have put off learning app development for so long. Let's say I was making a school timetable app, that all the user had to do was enter the name of their course, and then the app shows the timetable for that course..
The questions is can I get information from the college or do I have to hard code it into the database myself? 
How does one get information to use if they need it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Does the college provide you an interface you can use? Probably not one that was meant to be used by a third party app.

If not, then you have to somehow get the information into your database. Either per parsing their online HTML schedules or inputing it by hand (obviously always one of the last options to consider).

Comment: I was afraid of that...the website has no api to speak of..I would I parse their html schedules? Is it possible with android..

Comment: I would parse the site on a server and provide an interface for the android app. I wouldn't do heavy parsing on a mobile phone.

Comment: so do a php parse maybe. 
Then call the server where the file is or something

Answer (score 1):

If the college had a website that you could view, you could scan the page for class listings and pull that data in - but more than likely that sort of data will need to be entered manually by you when you ship the app.

Comment: how would I do that? I suppose, I could give parsing it a go.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with html parsing, you would basically just load the webpage in, and look for specific tags that enclose the data you need.  There are levels of simple to fancy html parses out there that could help you out. http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Answer (score 1):

If college is having its website and the website provides RSS feed for time table you parse that XML file and show the data which is parse or you can save the time table information of which course in the database and display that using cursors.

Comment: oh yes brilliant..I will check if it does. Good idea, thanks.